# AWSMobileClient: Access Token not refreshed automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Documentation says: "The tokens are automatically refreshed by the library when necessary.". I call

`AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getAccessToken().getTokenString();`
everytime before calling the API with AccessToken.
Here is what my awsconfiguration file looks like

```
`{
"IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
"CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "ap-xxxxx-1:2xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7xxxxxxxxxx",
            "Region": "ap-xxxxx-1"
        }
    }
},

"CognitoUserPool": {
    "Default": {
        "PoolId": "ap-xxxxx-1_xxxxxxxxx",
        "AppClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Region": "ap-xxxxx-1"
    }
}
```

After an hour, API returns 401(Authentication Error). 
And `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getAccessToken().getTokenString();` returns an error 
    `AWSMobileClient: Tokens are invalid, please sign-in again.
    java.lang.Exception: No cached session.`

Am I doing something wrong?
PS: I have not used Amplify CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was I was calling the getTokens() method from the main thread and it returned the tokens without refreshing. Then I moved the getTokens call inside the AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(..) call and I got refreshed tokens whenever required.